# Distinct in one row using JpaRepository and RestResource

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa, repository, jpql

i'm using JpaRepository with RestResource,i'm trying to return distinct list o "UNITE" of my class "Article".

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT a.unite from Article a")
public List<String> distinctunite();
```

but when i run the URL(http://localhost:8080/articles/search/distinctunite) i get this error.

```
{"cause":null,"message":"Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!"}
```

Comment: Could you post your `Article` entity?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? What version? Show us the `Article` code also.